# Find nth occurrence

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that generates a table similar to below, but the unique binder is duplicated for every image associated with it. I am trying to figure out a way for each additional column to return the nth occurrence of the associated images across the same row rather than creating a new row for each match.

**Current return:**

```
Binder ID   Image Name
 1943C6     FILE00000047.pdf
 1943C7     FILE00000389.pdf
 1943C7     FILE00000303.pdf
 1943C7     FILE00000048.pdf
 1943D5     FILE00000049.pdf
```

**Preferred:**

```
Binder ID   Image Name          Image Name          Image Name
 1943C6     FILE00000047.pdf        
 1943C7     FILE00000389.pdf    FILE00000303.pdf    FILE00000048.pdf
 1943D5     FILE00000049.pdf
```

Is it possible to have the preferred outcome using Microsoft Access 2010? Thanks

Comment: I would make the id column unique so there never can be duplicates. In your insert you can add an if then, I think ms access calls it `iif`. If binder id is a match, add new column, else add new row.  What have you tried?

Comment: I ended up just exporting everything into Excel and using VBA to get the format I needed then imported it back into Access. Not the most practical solution, but it works.